# Cauchy-Schwarz Proof Question

Tags: cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I'm just doing some revision on the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for Linear Algebra using this picture from my lecture notes:

[image]

The line:

'as a basic consequence of the dot product listed above, f(t) > 0 for all t as an element of the real numbers' has previously assumed that we assume that **b** is NOT the zero vector. This I understand.

What I don't understand if why no specification of **a** not being the zero vector is made. Surely if **a** was the zero vector, for t = 0, (**a**+t**b**) . (**a**+t**b**) = 0, and this would mean would mean that f(t) > 0 does **NOT** hold?

Am I missing something really obvious here?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It says $f(t) \ge 0$, not $f(t) > 0$.

Comment: In addition to Clement's answer, note that the case $\mathbf{a} = \mathbf{0}$ is pretty easy to handle.  In that case, equality *does* hold, and $\mathbf{a}$ is a scalar multiple of $\mathbf{b}$ (by $0$).

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Sorry about that - just have completed that now. Your answer made lots of sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No claim that $$\forall t\in\mathbb{R},\qquad f(t)>0$$ is ever made (as you note, this would indeed not be true for $t=0$). What is claimed is that $$\forall t\in\mathbb{R},\qquad f(t)\geq 0$$ 
which *is* true.

---

At a higher-level, *why is the assumption that $\mathbf{b}\neq \textbf{0}$ is even made?* It is only because for the rest of the proof we want $f(t)$ to be a degree-two polynomial (in $t$). Since $f(t) = \lVert \mathbf{b}\rVert^2 t^2 + 2t(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}) + \lVert \mathbf{a}\rVert^2$, this is only true of the coefficient if $t^2$ is non-zero.